# How can I remove the overlay (Date) on this WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

Link - http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/TheStyle/

Been poking around in Firebug for a few hours with no luck. Would appreciate anyone who can put me out of my misery.

Comment: delete the `<span class="month"....</span>` tag..did that in chrome in like 5 seconds

Comment: You're much smarter than I am then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<span>` with the date is wrapped in a `<span>` with a class of `month` so in your CSS add:

```
span.month { display: none; }
```